# Center fixed element inside container

Tags: css, position

I am currently working on a form that is supposed to be embedded into different websites via web components.
When the form was send and the API returned an error, a popup/modal/alert is supposed to show up centred horizontally at the top of the page. Since you can scroll the form and the error should always be visible i thought about positioning it fixed. However, this fixes it to the viewport. Since i have no influence on where the form is embedded, i would like to fix it to the form itself and not appear "somewhere" on the website.

I found that you can do that by positioning the container relative and using margin-top instead of top and that works for absolute values, but not for i.e 50%. I assume it uses 50% of the viewport width and not of the container with since it is really far off of the center.
Here is an example of what i tried:

```css
.container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 5000px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  position: relative;
  width: min(100%, 300px);
  margin: auto 200px;
}

.child {
  background-color: blue;
  position: fixed;
  margin-top: 3rem;
  margin-left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child">test</div>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/Nils-B-/pen/ZEZLMZm

Is there any way to actually do that in css or do i need js to position it absolutely on scroll?

Comment: I think that you will need as you said to position it absolute relative to scroll if you want to keep it centered within the parent element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please check the below solution? Hope it will work for you.

You can give `position: sticky;` to `child` element and other top value of this element.

```css
.container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 5000px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  position: relative;
  width: min(100%, 300px);
  margin: auto 200px;
}

.child {
  background-color: blue;
  position: sticky;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child">test</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, sorry, i forgot to specify that it should be centered horizontally in the container. But position sticky with 50% margin-left did it for me. thank you.

Comment: I'm pleased that my solution was helpful to you.